# Admin-ajax.php is dying "0" without processing function

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, jquery, ajax

I am trying to learn how to process AJAX requests in Wordpress the correct way. To do this I am adapting [this tutorial](http://wptheming.com/2013/07/simple-ajax-example/) to create a super simple AJAX request to place the ID of a post (from a link) into my page content.

**The Logic**

1. When the `#our-work a` links are clicked *[js]*
2. Get the post ID (from the `data-id` attribute) & store it as `postID` variable *[js]*
3. Pass `postID` via an AJAX (using the WP's `admin-ajax.php` file) *[js]*
4. The `example_ajax_request` function will pick up the ID & simply echo it *[php]*
5. If successful, append the server response to the `#hero` div.

I realise this has no benefit but once I have that working I will amend the function to serve a real purpose.

**My Code**

Here is a copy of the function I have created in the plugins folder:

```php
wp_enqueue_script( 'my-ajax-request', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'acl-plugin.js', array( 'jquery' ) );

wp_localize_script( 'my-ajax-request', 'MyAjax', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );

function example_ajax_request() {
    if ( isset($_REQUEST) ) {
        $postID = $_REQUEST['postID'];
        echo $postID;
    }
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

And here is a copy of the JS file

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $('#our-work a').click( function() {
        var postID = $(this).attr("data-id");

        $.ajax({
            url: MyAjax.ajaxurl,
            data: {
                'action':'example_ajax_request',
                'postID' : postID
            },
            success:function(data) {
                $('#hero').append( "Well this seems to work" + data );
            },
            error: function(errorThrown){
                console.log("This has thrown an error:" + errorThrown);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

**The Problem**

Upon clicking the link the JS does fire but yields the following response:

```
<div id="hero">
    Well this seems to work 0
</div>
```

Using an alert I know the ID is being picked up before the AJAX request. So the problem is in my function. To find out more, I (temporarily) tweaked WP's `admin-ajax.php` file, so that I could find out which `die();` was yielding the response of "0".

It is the very last one in the file which I thought wouldn't fire as I have a `die();` command in my own function. Can someone please point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Are you testing it as a logged in user?

Comment: Sorry @KrzysiekDróżdż I can't recall any details about this issue, it's over 5 years old. This approach is likely to antiquated now anyway.

Answer (score 4):

This is one of those rare times I can proudly say... there isn't any problem here!

The reason the server is returning with `0` is because I was logged in! The `wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request` is only for users who are **not** logged in. After logging out this works fine.

So if you are looking to do the same thing, just make sure you have both actions below the function:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another interesting thing to note is that Wordpress has it's own die() called wp_die().  I was getting that 0 at the end of my AJAX calls till I found it too.

```
echo(json_encode($return));
wp_die();
```

There's also [wp_send_json_success](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_success) and [wp_send_json_error](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_send_json_error).  All these return what you'd expect without the trailing 0.

```
wp_send_json_success($data);
```

will be returned as json with a data element

```
success: function(trn) {
    console.log(trn.data)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `wp_die();` insted of `die();` in function.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
function example_ajax_request() {

    // Your code goes here.        

    wp_die();
}
```